# Select "lowest value" from table for multiple "ids"

Tags: mysql

I read up last night on using the sql MIN() and I understand how it works now. However, I was wondering, how do I run

```
SELECT MIN(card_price)
FROM card_lookup_values
```

and display the lowest "price" for each individual card. A lot of the cards have 5-9 prices in the card_price column. I guess I was looking for:

```
 card_id   card_price
    0001      2
    0002      99
    0003      22.3
```

Comment: `GROUP BY card_name` is my best-guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `group by card_name`.

Consider reading this tutorial on aggregate functions:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/tutorial-agg.html

Comment: Thanks Denis. I never really know where to go to learn about mysql.

Comment: In that case, try the PostgreSQL docs. They're the best around imho.